# Android studio showing nothing to show

Tags: android

My android studio is showing blank screen and showing "nothing to show" in properties and layout, how to solve this issue. Please help me regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started to build a project?

Either from the pre built templates that Android Studio offers. Or by importing one that has already been created?